# Vuetify datatable Rows per page is not working

Tags: vuetify.js

[image: Here is the problem and how this shows inside component]I imported the datatable component from Vuetify and it is working fine except for the `Rows per page` part. It doesn't open a list that should contain [5, 10, 20] to re-organize the datatable.

**update** in the photo this is the error, the list of options showing in another place.

I reviewed my code and there is nothing about it. So I deleted the whole component and replaced it with the basic example available in the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#data-table) but still the same problem.

```
<template>
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:items="props">
      <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

and the code script part is

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'left',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name'
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
          { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
          { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 237,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '1%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,
            protein: 6.0,
            iron: '7%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 305,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '8%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 356,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,
            protein: 3.9,
            iron: '16%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 375,
            fat: 0.0,
            carbs: 94,
            protein: 0.0,
            iron: '0%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 392,
            fat: 0.2,
            carbs: 98,
            protein: 0,
            iron: '2%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 408,
            fat: 3.2,
            carbs: 87,
            protein: 6.5,
            iron: '45%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 452,
            fat: 25.0,
            carbs: 51,
            protein: 4.9,
            iron: '22%'
          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 518,
            fat: 26.0,
            carbs: 65,
            protein: 7,
            iron: '6%'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

What should I re-check ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behaviour happens, when the template isn't within a `<v-app>` element.
In the main `app.vue`, from which one calls the component, which uses`<v-data-table>`, encapsule with `<v-app>` and `<v-content>`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <myComponent></myComponent>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>
```

Compare to a vuetify tutorial, e.g.[a random tutorial](https://appdividend.com/2018/02/12/vuetify-tutorial-example-scratch/).

It seems the dropdowns css class position (`top` and `left`) is relative to the pagination element if `<v-app>` is missing and relative to the 0-position (upper left) of the vuetify table, if the data table is correctly encapsuled.

Answer (score 3):

Add `:pagination.sync="pagination"` to your `<v-data-table>`:

```
<template>
   <v-data-table
       :headers="headers"
       :items="desserts"
       :pagination.sync="pagination"
       class="elevation-1"
   >
   <template v-slot:items="props">
      <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
   </template>
 </v-data-table>
</template>
```

and in your `data` object:

```
<script>
  export default {
     data () {
        return {
           pagination: {
                ascending: true,
                sortBy:"name",
                rowsPerPage: 5,
                page: 1
            }
         ....
          }
        }
       }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but there were two Vuetify components with the `<v-app>` wrapper (don't ask) and it causes that dropdown offset problem.

Adding the `data-app` attribute to the `<body>` element helped me:

```html
<body data-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, issue was the `:items-per-page` property had to be set to a value that was also in the dropdown selection or else it defaulted to 5 even though it displayed the correct number of rows per page. That is, the problem was thatthe drop down default selection was 5 despite actually showing N (e.g. 20) rows per page.